# How to properly add Apache Commons jar to class path?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, apache-commons, japplet

I'm trying to convert a base64 string into a string for which I'm using the Apache Commons Base64 class. This conversion functionality is to be incorporated into a Java web applet being developed in NetBeans. When I try to run the web applet, the web applet claims that there is a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64` at the stage where I try to do a base64 conversion.

I've tried right-clicking on the project and selecting properties and adding

> commons-codec-1.7.jar

to my list of libraries.

I've also tried including the commons-codec-1.7.jar file in WEB-INF/lib directory, as well as in the same path as the html file that is used to launch my web applet. In all circumstances, the

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

keeps showing up.

I am not sure why this is happening and I am currently stuck as a result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "Right-clicking" implies that you're using an IDE. Which one? Also, show your `<applet>` config.

Comment: @Lion: I added the commons-codec-1.7.jar to libraries as shown in the screenshot I just added above. The NetBeans IDE itself seems to acknowledge that the library exists, seeing as it does not report any errors when I try to clean and build the project. The error seems to be happening when I run it as a web applet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply adding the JAR file to the `WEB-INF/lib` will not work. You need to ensure that the JAR is available for download and that it is included in the applet tag archive list:

```
<applet code="MyApplet.class" width=640 height=480 archive="myapplet.jar,commons-codec-1.7.jar">
</applet>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I forgot something so fundamental. This did the trick.